# How to Access Many Nested Child Firebase Realtime database into RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

Can anyone here help me?

how to display the "Episode" and "Pemeran" sections in the recyclerView on the second display in the following image.

I use the same method as "liveTV" but it doesn't work / appears anything, because of the many children in the Episode and Pemeran tables?

please help, thank you

Firebase Realtime-database picture]

[image: firebase]

Application Concept

[image: concept]

**dbDrakorAdapter.java** - Models

```
public class dbDrakorAdapter {
private String LinkMovie;
private String List;
private String FotoPemain;
private String NamaPemain;


public dbDrakorAdapter (String linkMovie, String list, String fotoPemain, String namaPemain) {
    LinkMovie = linkMovie;
    List = list;
    FotoPemain = fotoPemain;
    NamaPemain = namaPemain;


}
public class Episode {
    List<EpisodeDetails> episodeDetails;
}

public class EpisodeDetails {
   // public Long chapterId;
    public String LinkMovie;
    public String List;
}
public class Pemeran {
    List<PemeranDetails> pemeranDetails;
}

public class PemeranDetails {
    // public Long chapterId;
    public String LinkMovie;
    public String List;
}
@PropertyName("LinkMovie")
public String getLinkMovie() { return LinkMovie; }
@PropertyName("List")
public String getList() { return List; }
@PropertyName("FotoPemain")
public String getFotoPemain() { return FotoPemain; }
@PropertyName("NamaPemain")
public String getNamaPemain() { return NamaPemain; }

@Exclude
public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
    HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put("List", List);
    result.put("LinkMovie", LinkMovie);
    result.put("FotoPemain", FotoPemain);
    result.put("NamaPemain", NamaPemain);
    return result;
}
}
```

**DrakorActivity.Java**

```
public class DrakorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView mEpisodeRV,mPemeranRV;
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<dbDrakorAdapter, DrakorActivity.ListEpisode> mListEpisodeAdapter;
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<dbDrakorAdapter, DrakorActivity.ListPemeran> mListPemeranAdapter;

FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drakor);

    DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("SerialDrakor").child("Episode");
    Query personsQuery = database.orderByKey();
    mEpisodeRV = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.cRecylerDrakorEpisode);
    mEpisodeRV.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mEpisodeRV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions personsOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<dbDrakorAdapter>().setQuery(personsQuery, dbDrakorAdapter.class).build();

    mListEpisodeAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<dbDrakorAdapter, ListEpisode>(personsOptions) {

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(DrakorActivity.ListEpisode holder, int position, final dbDrakorAdapter model ) {
            holder.setList(model.getList());

            holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(DrakorActivity.this,"Ini Hanya Iklan , Tidak Dapat Digunakan",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }


        @Override
        public DrakorActivity.ListEpisode onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_drakor_episode, parent, false);

            return new DrakorActivity.ListEpisode(view);


        }



    };
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
    mEpisodeRV.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mEpisodeRV.setAdapter(mListEpisodeAdapter);

}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mListEpisodeAdapter.startListening();
  //  mListPemeranAdapter.startListening();

}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mListEpisodeAdapter.stopListening();
  //  mListPemeranAdapter.stopListening();

}

//Episode
public static class ListEpisode extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    View mView;
    public ListEpisode(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }
    public void setList (String list){
        TextView post_title = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.TxtlistEpisode);
        post_title.setText(list);
    }
}
```

**activity_drakor.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/drakorLyEpisode"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/drakorThumbnail"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"

    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/cRecylerDrakorEpisode"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**item_drakor_episode.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="60dp"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#090000"
    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TxtlistEpisode"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="1"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your FirebaseRecyclerAdapters are using the same POJO but they are going to display different information.
For example:

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<EpisodePojo, DrakorActivity.ListEpisode> listEpisodesAdapter
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<PemeranPojo, DrakorActivity.ListPemeran> listPemeranAdapter
```

Your code is not showing any information probably because your DatabaseReference is trying to access "Episode as a child of SerialDrakor" but "SerialDrakor" is a list of objects, therefore, your code will not be able to parse a list of "SerialDrakor" child into "Episode".

You have to retrieve "SerialDrakor" as a list and use the child you need from this list to retrieve the "Episode" and "Pemeran" inside of it.

Here you can see some examples, maybe would be a good idea to use a custom parser.

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database#using-the-firebaserecycleradapter

Update: What I would do is create a class parsing a "SerialDrakor" item.

```
class SerialDrakor {
   List<Episode> episodeList;
   List<Pemeran> pemeranList;

   .....
}
```

Then use a query to retrieve "SerialDrakor"

```
DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query serialDrakorQuery = database.child("SerialDrakor").orderByKey();
FirebaseRecyclerOptions personsOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<SerialDrakor>().setQuery(serialDrakorQuery, new SnapshotParser<SerialDrakor>() {
@Override
public SerialDrakor parseSnapshot(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
   // Here fetch the data you want and pass it to your adapters
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: can you help me solve this problem? using the method you mentioned? I have run out of ideas to solve this problem 

Comment: i get error : incompatible types.
Required:
com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions
<>
Found:
com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder
<com.example.SerialDrakor>

Answer (score 0):

On deep seeing your firebase structure it is difficult to query as you said.So you can change your firebase structure as below

```
Episode
     |
     |__Unique_Key
           |
           |__LinkMovie:"asasa.com
           |__List:"1"
           |__Epi:"1"
  Pemeran
      |
      |__UniqueKey
             |__fotoPermain:"...."
             |__NamaPemain:"Ronny"
             |__permeranId:"1"
```

Here,SubNode `1` in your Episode and pemeran Node in your firebase structure is replace as the Child Node of Unique Key.
You can generate Unique Key by `push()`

Comment: are there other solutions?

Comment: No,You can try this.This structure helps you to query easily